# DateTimeKind is Unspecified Even Though I Set it

Tags: c#, datetime, datetimeoffset

When I check `optionDate`'s `DateTime` property's `DateTimeKind` value, I see Unspecified, even though I set dt's `DateTimeKind` as UTC in below code. I expect `optionDate` has a `DateTime` which has a `DateTimeKind` property set to UTC. Where am I wrong here?

```
       var dt = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(optionDateInfo.dateTime.year),
            Convert.ToInt32(optionDateInfo.dateTime.month), Convert.ToInt32(optionDateInfo.dateTime.day),
            Convert.ToInt32(optionDateInfo.dateTime.hour), Convert.ToInt32(optionDateInfo.dateTime.minutes),
            0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

        var optionDate = new DateTimeOffset(dt);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is documented:

[`DateTimeOffset.DateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.datetime?view=net-5.0#remarks)

> The value of the DateTime.Kind property of the returned DateTime object is DateTimeKind.Unspecified.

Note that a `DateTimeOffset` does not have a "kind". It has a date, time, and offset. When you pass your `DateTime` with kind `Utc`, to it, it sets its offset to 0, and its date & time to the `DateTime` given. At this point, your `DateTimeKind` is "lost".

An offset of 0 does not necessarily mean that its kind is `DateTimeKind.Utc`. It could be the local time in London, or somewhere in Africa too. So it can't give you a `DateTime` with kind `Utc` just because its offset is 0 either.

In addition, `DateTime` being able to represent 3 kinds of things is already a questionable design, and if the `DateTime` property can now return 3 different kinds of `DateTime` depending on whether offset matches the local time, is UTC, or something else, that's just even worse.

Instead, it is designed to have 3 properties that give you `DateTime`s with different kinds.

- [`DateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.datetime?view=net-5.0#System_DateTimeOffset_DateTime) gives you the date & time part of the `DateTimeOffset`, with kind `Unspecified`
- [`LocalDateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.localdatetime?view=net-5.0) converts the date & time part of the `DateTimeOffset` to the current timezone, and gives you a `DateTime` with kind `Local`.
- [`UtcDateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.utcdatetime?view=net-5.0) converts the date & time part of the `DateTimeOffset` to UTC, and gives you a `DateTime` with kind `Utc`.

If you want a `DateTime` with kind `Utc`, you should use that last one.

Answer (score 0):

Use the SpecifyKind

```
var myUtcZeroOffset = DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.UtcNow, DateTimeKind.Utc)

//If constructing a datetime offset to be not utc you can supply the offset instead
var myOffSetExplicitLocal = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now, new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0));
var localDateTime = myOffSetExplicitLocal.DateTime;
var utcZeroOffSetDateTime = myOffSetExplicitLocal.UtcDateTime;
```

To make matters worse of cause it is a criticisable implementation from Microsoft, because Universally Coordinated Time is not a timezone but a notation, as per ISO 8601, so in fact toUTC as a concept is flawed because '2021-11-02T10:16:25.12345+01:00' is completely valid in the UTC format and UTC Zero offset, popularily called Zulu being the '2021-11-02T09:16:25.12345Z' equivalent which then gets datetimekind UTC is actually just in coordinated time the zero line around GMT latitude, but what makes it coordinated is the + part which in +00:00 can be abbreviated to Z, so lots of stuff is done to mitigate the inherent conflict and with build servers and cloud providers the .Local is especially dubious, so I would recommend always to persist in ISO 8601 strings instead, unless you actually need to use them in with date operations in Your DB, in said case to name fields appropriate like DateTimeCreatedUtcZero column e.g.
just my five cents of reason on the topic in general, hope it helps.